# Magento 1.9.1 Catalog price rule "is not one of" doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules

I am using Magento 1.9.1 and I trying to implement this Catalog Price Rule:

**IF ALL** these conditions are **TRUE**

SKU **is not one of** SKU1, SKU2, SKU3 -->*This rule doesn't works.*

*It works only on this way:*

SKU **is not one of** SKU1

SKU **is not one of** SKU2

SKU **is not one of** SKU3

Is this a magento Bug?

Comment: It's a long shot, but perhaps you entered the spaces you put above in Magento and it's seeing the space as part of the SKU, thus it doesn't match.

Comment: I believe this is a Magento bug - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54927/magento-is-one-of-condition-in-1-9-1-0?noredirect=1#comment73895_54927

Comment: @DouglasRadburn perhaps a solution would just be to override this rule and implement your own working method?  Doesn't seem that hard you'd only need to change like.. one or two lines.