# "is one of" condition in catalog price rules not working

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, price-rules, bug

In magento 1.9.1.0 "is one of" and "is not one of" conditions dont work in catalog price rules with multiple skus listed.

Condition sku is "xxx" works fine.  However, sku is one of "xxx", "yyy". Makes rule not work.  It is a confirmed bug from my previous research on the issue.  I'm looking for a local overide fix.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the rules you're looking to set up?

Comment: I appreciate your response, but it is a bug with 1.9.1.0.  I'm trying to get someone aware of the bug and how to fix.  Many users will benefit from this.   The condition is easily replicable in 1.9.1.0.  Set any rule up and make a rule that should be active if 'sku is one of' or 'sku is not one of'  Select two or more skus the rule should apply to.   Enable and activate the rule, and you will see the promotion does not apply.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36195/catalog-price-rule-containing-several-sku-s-doesnt-work ?

Comment: Actually this is slightly different.  In **1.9.0.1** there was a bug with more than one 'is one of' conditions in the same rule.  In 1.9.1.0 the bug happens with a single 'is one of' condition.  I'm certain as my rules worked on 1.9.0.1 and broke in 1.9.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebear studio has a fix here by modifying two core files, and copying to local directory.  http://firebearstudio.com/blog/catalog-price-rules-core-bug-in-magento-ce-1-9-1-and-ee-1-14-1-0-array-to-string-conversion-error-and-incorrect-price-rules-behavior.html

Comment: I would love to see some of that blog post in this answer as links and die. Also did you contact Magento about this issue direclty? Finally feel free to accept the answer if this fixes the issue.